# Best way to control Word from Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, vsto, openxml

I am updating a Windows Forms application that was written for Office 2003. It would open Word, populate it with text from the database, create buttons appropriate for the user's security roles, and handle button clicks. The old way was with CommandBars. The Word documents created this way were stored as DB Blobs, so they were only ever available via the Forms application. That is the functionality I need, but without CommandBars.

Now, we have the Ribbon, Action Panes, VSTO, and OpenXML. I know my way around C#, but I'm new to all of these technologies.

I imagine a solution where I set up a template with the proper buttons on a nice ribbon, and the buttons raise events. If someone just tried to use the template by itself, there would be no data and the events would do nothing. But my Windows Form could create a new document based on the template, populate it with text from the database, hide inappropriate buttons, and handle button click events. Easy peasy.

I began by adding a Word 2010 Template project and making a ribbon for it. It looks nice in the debugger. But, I can't create a new document with it from a Console app. Word launches, but the ribbon isn't there. There's a note in the documentation that "If a Microsoft Office Word template has managed code extensions, the project assembly is not called if the template is attached as a global template or loaded from the startup directory of Word. In addition, the document does not recognize the format of a template that is part of an Office solution." I believe this means my template is useless. I can't open Word and make a new document with my template or call the template from another project, so, pointless.

All the MS help has failed me, and mostly leads me in circles. I need some direction. For each piece of the scenario I described, what is the most appropriate modern technology? For each technology I need to use, what is the best resource for my situation?

Comment: I've progressed a little in this. I see now that when you make a Word template in VSTO, you can't just use it. You have to publish it, then install it, then use it. That's normal for Visual Studio, I just wasn't expecting it because it's a Word template.

Comment: After installing the template in My Documents, I tried copying it into my test Console app to use. The copy doesn't work, but if I point to the original that the setup.exe created, it does work. So, I can now make a new Word document based on a template and the template has C# logic in it. Halfway there, I guess. The next thing I need to do is to pass messages from my app to the new Word document that will hide Ribbon buttons. I'm guessing OpenXML will be the way to do that, but any guidance would be most appreciated.